# Keeping or killing unused service

Tags: android, android-service

I am using a `Service` in my music player to handle the `MediaPlayer`. Following is the what I do in my `Activity` to handle the Service:

```
boolean serviceStarted = false; // I store this in saveInstanstanceState

protected void onResume(){
    super.onStart();
    // mBound is boolean that is set in onServiceConnected
    if(!mBound){ 
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        if(!serviceStarted){ 
             startService(intent);
             serviceStarted = true;
        }
        bindService(intent);
    }
}

protected onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mBound){
        unbindService(mConnection); // mConnection is my ServiceConnection
        mBound = false;
    }
}
```

Now I had recognized that if a user removes my App from the recently used Apps, the Service is not killed. But since I assume a user wants to (at least) stop the music by removing it from the recently used Apps, I would like to kill the Service there.
Therefore I have added this to the `Activity`:

```
boolean orientationChange = false;

public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
    orientationChange = true;
    return super.onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
}

protected void onDestroy(){
     if(!orientationChange){
            stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));  
     }
}
```

This works for now, but since `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` is deprecated, I don't want to keep this. But I also don't want to kill the Service when orientation changes..
What other possibilities do I have?

Comment: I would use `startService()` and `stopService()`, rather than `bindService()` and `unbindService()`, for a music player: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Service/FakePlayer

Comment: Hm, this would probably work, if I can still call `startService()` in `onDestroy()`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uee a while loop in your service with some condition.
Change this condition to false if you want to stop your service. This will stop your service from executing code and the OS will stop your service.

Comment: I am not aware of any environment in which a busy loop is considered a good programming practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I assume CommonsWare is right in that point.